# NPAPI: How to add new method or property into global scope (window object)

Tags: npapi

In my NPAPI plain plugin I want to add some new properties and methods into global scope (window object) e.g.

```
var status = window.myFunction();
```

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have code examples with me, but basically what you need to do is get the NPObject for the DOM window and then you can call NPN_SetProperty on it to set a value.  You can create a NPObject that responds to InvokeDefault and assign that object to "myFunction" on the window and you're done.

[FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) makes this a lot easier with wrapper functions and such, but it's doing the same thing underneath.